# How I can make proper use of Generic?

Tags: java, generics

```
public class GenericClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Hat<Integer> marks = new Hat<Integer>();
        marks.tell(4);
        Hat<String> apple = new Hat<String>();
        apple.tell("apple");
    }
}

class Hat<T> {
    void tell(T an) {
        System.out.println(an + " is good");
    }

    void tell(String fu) {
        System.out.println(fu + " is healthy");
    }
}
```

How is `apple.tell("apple")` ambiguous? I am trying check how many different ways I can make use of Generic.

Comment: Which of the two `tell` methods would you like to call in the second instance?

Comment: How is `apple.tell("apple")` _not_ ambiguous?  If `T` means `String`, then both your `tell` methods have the same signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apple.tell("apple")
```

> is an String and

```
void tell(T an) {
    System.out.println(an + " is good");
}
```

> T Become String for "apple" so compiler encounter Two String & Overloading is also  there so it is ambiguous